# Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'DevExpress.Web.Mvc.DevExpressEditorsBinder'

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress, plesk

This is the first time I have published my website on a public server.

I have a domain with plesk control panel.

After I published my app, I got this error.

**Inheritance security rules violated by type: "DevExpress.Web.Mvc.DevExpressEditorsBinder". Derived types must match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.**

Before that I publish my app to my local server (Windows Server 2016, iis 10.0.14393.0) and it works normally.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aAG0.png)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the fact that you are referencing the DevExpress.Web.Mvc assembly in the MVC5 application (in the project References list and in Web.config). Note that it is necessary to use the DevExpress.Web.Mvc5 assembly instead. Please refer to the [MVC 5 / Razor 3 breaking changes cause security violations under the Medium .NET Trusted Level](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/b239257/mvc-5-razor-3-breaking-changes-cause-security-violations-under-the-medium-net-trusted#) ticket where this issue was already discussed for more information.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
I am using the devexpress.web.mvc5.dll.
And the trust level = "Full".
She does not work.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI4z2.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKugN.png

Comment: I think iis may not support devexpress.web.mvc5.dll, you can ask for help in devexpress forums, or find a Microsoft .dll to replace it.